# Why doesn't svg file work in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I dont have any error, but it doesnt work.

I have a Search bar on the screen. Before the placeholder, i want to show a search icon there. As I know, I did what i needed to get this worked. I installed `npm install react-native-svg --save` and `npm install react-native-svg-transformer --save` And I added new code into metro.config.js But there must be something missing as it doesnt work.

Here is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Search from "./src/icons/search.svg";

const App = () => {
 

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.firstPart}>
        <Text style={styles.date}>Saturday, Feb 21</Text>
        <View style={styles.package}>
          <Text style={styles.packageText}>Your Package</Text>
          <View style={styles.plusIcon}>
            <Text style={styles.textPlus}>+</Text>
          </View>
          <Search width={120} height={40} />
        </View>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Search" placeholderTextColor="gray"></TextInput>
      </View>


    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    margin:10,

  },
  firstPart:{
    backgroundColor: "mediumblue",
    borderTopRightRadius:40,
    borderTopLeftRadius:40,
    padding:20,
  },
  date:{
    fontSize:15,
    color:"white",
  },
  package:{
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  packageText: {
    fontSize:25,
    color:"white",
    flexDirection: "column",
    
    
  },
  plusIcon: {
    height:25,
    width:25,
    borderRadius:25,
    backgroundColor:"blue",
    marginTop:5,
   
  },
  textPlus: {
    fontSize:25,
    fontWeight:"bold",
    color:"white",
    marginLeft:5,
  },
  input: {
    height:40,
    borderWidth:.5,
    borderRadius:10,
    marginVertical:10,
  }
});

export default App;
```

metro.config.js

```
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();
```

src/icons/search.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M310,190c-5.52,0-10,4.48-10,10s4.48,10,10,10c5.52,0,10-4.48,10-10S315.52,190,310,190z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M500.281,443.719l-133.48-133.48C388.546,277.485,400,239.555,400,200C400,89.72,310.28,0,200,0S0,89.72,0,200
            s89.72,200,200,200c39.556,0,77.486-11.455,110.239-33.198l36.895,36.895c0.005,0.005,0.01,0.01,0.016,0.016l96.568,96.568
            C451.276,507.838,461.319,512,472,512c10.681,0,20.724-4.162,28.278-11.716C507.837,492.731,512,482.687,512,472
            S507.837,451.269,500.281,443.719z M305.536,345.727c0,0.001-0.001,0.001-0.002,0.002C274.667,368.149,238.175,380,200,380
            c-99.252,0-180-80.748-180-180S100.748,20,200,20s180,80.748,180,180c0,38.175-11.851,74.667-34.272,105.535
            C334.511,320.988,320.989,334.511,305.536,345.727z M326.516,354.793c10.35-8.467,19.811-17.928,28.277-28.277l28.371,28.371
            c-8.628,10.183-18.094,19.65-28.277,28.277L326.516,354.793z M486.139,486.139c-3.78,3.78-8.801,5.861-14.139,5.861
            s-10.359-2.081-14.139-5.861l-88.795-88.795c10.127-8.691,19.587-18.15,28.277-28.277l88.798,88.798
            C489.919,461.639,492,466.658,492,472C492,477.342,489.919,482.361,486.139,486.139z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M200,40c-88.225,0-160,71.775-160,160s71.775,160,160,160s160-71.775,160-160S288.225,40,200,40z M200,340
            c-77.196,0-140-62.804-140-140S122.804,60,200,60s140,62.804,140,140S277.196,340,200,340z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M312.065,157.073c-8.611-22.412-23.604-41.574-43.36-55.413C248.479,87.49,224.721,80,200,80c-5.522,0-10,4.478-10,10
            c0,5.522,4.478,10,10,10c41.099,0,78.631,25.818,93.396,64.247c1.528,3.976,5.317,6.416,9.337,6.416
            c1.192,0,2.405-0.215,3.584-0.668C311.472,168.014,314.046,162.229,312.065,157.073z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used your svg file to see if it works and it is visible only if you set a `fill` property to it.
Like this

```js
<Search width={120} height={40} fill={"#00FF00"}/>

// Putting the icon inside text field; sorry for the inline styling

  <View 
    style={{position: 'absolute', top: 10, zIndex: 20}}
   >
    <Search height={30} width={30} fill={"#00FF00"}/>
  </View>
  <TextInput
  style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', height: 50, paddingLeft: 50}}                      placeholder="Search" placeholderTextColor="gray"
  />
  
  // You will have to change that top style in accordance to your layout of course
```

EDIT

As per my knowledge, that placeholder can only be a string. But anyway, you can obtain what you've said. You can have a state called, let's say `isTextInputFocused` which will become true when textInput is focused and false when it is blurred (implement onFocus & onBlur to change that state) and then,

```js
{ !isTextInputFocused && ( <View 
    style={{position: 'absolute', top: 10, zIndex: 20}}
   >
    <Search height={30} width={30} fill={"#00FF00"}/>
  </View> )}
```

Basically, conditionally display that image by a variable you manipulate

Comment: Thank you a lot.. I couldnt find the solution for hours..

Comment: Do you have any  guess about how I could pass it in placeholder part? so it will be seen before "Search" text

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean :(  do you want to display that icon inside the textInput as a placeholder? If you can, please share an image

Comment: no Sir :D I meant I want to use this icon in this element: ` <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Search" placeholderTextColor="gray"></TextInput> `
so icon will be seen first in the text input, then Search text

Comment: So your question is correct actually, i want to use the icon in placeholder as you said inside the TextInput,  icon and Search will be written in placeholder

Comment: I updated the answer (https://imgur.com/aEwhc15 - here is my ugly version of it)

Comment: Thank you for your work. But am i wrong? I guess that wasnt what i asked for. Because here the icon will still be there, but i thought when i clicked on the textInput, icon and "search" text would be deleted.  

so its not possible to get the icon and a text inside textInput as placeholder? sorry i ask too much

Comment: Updated it. I implemented what you want many times and each time this was a solution I always used. If it's somehow relevant, on the ios native side, the placeholder also has only this purpose - to be a string

Comment: Thank you so much. It was easier when i do it before using icon. But using icon is like a bit harder when i look at codes. I am beginner tho, 
i try to learn react-native, do u have any suggestion about how to learn?

Comment: This one, the latest version, when you need to use both

Comment: I am trying to learn react native for 2-3 weeks, but i feel i dont progress very well. What would you recommend me? I have to learn and be able to do things in react-native tho

Comment: Can you look at my new question when u have time? its about this, i just tried to use ternany operator to make SearchIcon active and passive, but it doesnt work like i wanted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67489802/whats-my-mistake-when-using-ternany-operator-with-istextinputfocused-property-i