# What's my mistake when using ternany operator with isTextInputFocused property in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I have a textInput. When i click on the textInput, i want "Search Icon" to be passive, but when i dont click on the textInput, i want "Search Icon" to be active,

Its strangely not doing what I want. As I look at my code, it looks correct, but i must have something wrong because it doesnt work as i wanted.(not giving an error tho)

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, isTextInputFocused } from 'react-native';
import Search from "./src/icons/search.svg";
import {Loupe} from "./src/icons/loupe.png";
const App = () => {
 

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.firstPart}>
        <Text style={styles.date}>Saturday, Feb 21</Text>
        <View style={styles.package}>
          <Text style={styles.packageText}>Your Package</Text>
          <View style={styles.plusIcon}>
            <Text style={styles.textPlus}>+</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        {isTextInputFocused ? (<Search height={25} width={20} fill={"#00FF00"} style={{ position: "absolute", top: 90, left: 30, zIndex: 0 }} />):
          (<Search height={25} width={20} fill={"#A9A9A9"} style={{ position: "absolute", top: 90, left: 25, zIndex: 20 }}/>)}
        
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Search" placeholderTextColor="gray"></TextInput>
      </View>

   {/*    { !isTextInputFocused && (<View>
        <Search height={30} width={30} fill={"#00FF00"} />
      </View>)} */}
  


    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    margin:10,

  },
  firstPart:{
    backgroundColor: "mediumblue",
    borderTopRightRadius:40,
    borderTopLeftRadius:40,
    padding:20,
  },
  date:{
    fontSize:15,
    color:"white",
  },
  package:{
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  packageText: {
    fontSize:25,
    color:"white",
    flexDirection: "column",
    
    
  },
  plusIcon: {
    height:25,
    width:25,
    borderRadius:25,
    backgroundColor:"blue",
    marginTop:5,
   
  },
  textPlus: {
    fontSize:25,
    fontWeight:"bold",
    color:"white",
    marginLeft:5,
  },
  input: {
    height:40,
    borderWidth:.5,
    borderRadius:10,
    marginVertical:10,
    backgroundColor:"darkslateblue",
    padding:5,
  }
});
```

export default App;

Comment: As the answer below mentioned, you have to implement the methods `onFocus`, `onBlur` from `TextInput` in order to store the state you need. Think it like this: your textInput does something, whether  changes value or is focused/is blurred, then you need to know when that happens - that happens in the methods already existing, they are like a blueprint, but you have to implement them in order to do inside them whatever you may need

Comment: I thought i didnt need to use onFocus and onBlur when I use isTextFocused.. So i need to use onFocus, and onBlur.. Alright, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TextInput component's [onFocus](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onfocus), [onBlur](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onblur) props to focus information on an input. Sample code is available below.

```
  const [text, setText] = useState("")
  const [inputFocus, setFocus] = useState(false)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>
        {inputFocus ? "Focused" : "Not Focused"}
      </Text>

      <TextInput
        value={text}
        onChangeText={setText}
        onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
        onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: 44,
          backgroundColor: "gray"
        }}
      />
    </View>
  )
```